# Stop NatTable from going into edit mode when an editable cell is left-mouse-clicked

Tags: nattable

NatTable's default behavior when an editable cell is left-mouse-clicked is to immediately launch the cell's editor.

Users sometimes left-click simply to toss focus into the table, and then use the arrow keys to navigate around inside of it.  Given the table's default behavior, they first need to dismiss the edit operation via ENTER, ESCAPE, etc. before they can move the cell selection.

I'd like to alter this behavior so that a left-mouse-click selects the cell that was clicked, but does not instigate an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editing triggers are configured in the `org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.edit.config.DefaultEditBindings` class, which is used by `org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.config.DefaultGridLayerConfiguration`.

All you have to do is register a different grid layer configuration which uses a different edit bindings. For example:

```
        GridLayer gridLayer = new GridLayer(bodyLayer, columnHeaderLayer, rowHeaderLayer, cornerLayerStack, false) {

        @Override
        protected void init(boolean useDefaultConfiguration) {
            super.init(useDefaultConfiguration);
            addConfiguration(new DefaultGridLayerConfiguration(this) {

                @Override
                protected void addEditingUIConfig() {
                    addConfiguration(new DefaultEditBindings() {

                        @Override
                        public void configureUiBindings(
                                UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
                            super.configureUiBindings(uiBindingRegistry);

                            //update bindings as you wish
                        }


                    });
                }


            });
        }

    };
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I had to add all of the binding registrations from DefaultEditBindings _except_ for the one I didn't want: registerSingleClickBinding().  I'd hoped I could simply call the superclass and then use uiBindingRegistry.unregisterSingleClickBinding(), but I couldn't provide a MouseEvent that matched what had been registered.  Also note that in your example, super.init(useDefaultConfiguration) should be super.init(false), otherwise all of the default bindings will be registered before you get a chance to override.

Comment: since NatTable 1.3 unregistering should also work correctly with uiBindingRegistry.unregisterSingleClickBinding(new CellEditorMouseEventMatcher(GridRegion.BODY));
You don't need a MouseEvent but the MouseEventMatcher, which should be the same as for registering.