# NatTable allow cell editing only when cell is selected

Tags: nattable

Working with a NatTable, I would like the following behavior:

- Single click on an unselected, editable cell - cell is selected
- Double-click on a cell (at any time), do custom open action
- Single-click on a *selected* cell triggers an edit

Do I need to write a custom IEditableRule that checks selection?  If there a way to check the selection from w/i this rule, or do I need to also create a rule that can listen to the entire table selection and unify these concepts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register custom bindings for editing. The default bindings are registered via `DefaultEditBindings`. You need to replace them with bindings for double click to open the editor and some customized actions that check the selection. For the key bindings NatTable uses the same approach. It is not the default to check the selection because of abstraction and it should be possible to edit even if you have no `SelectionLayer` in place.

To check if the cell is selected you either need a reference to `SelectionLayer` or check the `DisplayMode` of the cell. Never tried to use a `IEditableRule` for this.

Maybe these posts give you some more information:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/452759/

[Stop NatTable from going into edit mode when an editable cell is left-mouse-clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410939/stop-nattable-from-going-into-edit-mode-when-an-editable-cell-is-left-mouse-clic)